# Google Sites embedding external and off-YouTube video

Tags: video, youtube, google-sites

I have video that I want to embed into a Google Site.  I don't want it on YouTube or any of its ilk, however, and Google Video is a royal pain to submit to.  Is there any way to embed video in Google Sites without first putting the video on YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

There are several gadgets available on the list of additional gadgets that allow you to embed iframes, objects, and sfw objects. You can select the best gadget for your site based upon the embedable type the video site provides.